# UITextField should change characters in range looping on false return

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit, uitextfielddelegate

I have a textfield that I auto format for phone numbers.  It inserts "(,),-" appropriately and manually implements a max length.  This is done through:

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

The issue is when the the `textField` hits the max character, it limits it and buzzes the device (as expected), but it does this on a loop forever.  I put a `println` in the delegate method and its getting called multiple times per second.  I couldn't find anything related to this while searching the web.  Can anyone point me in the right direction towards some help?

Here is the delegate method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let backspacing = (countElements(string) == 0) ? true : false
    let newCharNum = (backspacing) ? -1 : 1

    // validate phone number is >= 10 characters
    if countElements(textfield.phoneNumber) + newCharNum > 10 {
        println("TWO much")
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1352)
        return false
    }

    // validate character is number
    if !backspacing && "0123456789".rangeOfString(string) == nil {
        println("too much")
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1352)
        return false
    }

    // color phone number header accordingly
    if countElements(textfield.phoneNumber) + newCharNum == 10 {
        textfield.valid = true
    }else{
        textfield.valid = false
    }

    // add/delete char accordingly
    if backspacing && countElements(textfield.phoneNumber) > 0 {
        textfield.phoneNumber = dropLast(textfield.phoneNumber)
    } else {
        textfield.phoneNumber += string
    }

    // format new number
    var tempStr:String = ""
    var count = 0
    for character in textfield.phoneNumber {
        if (count == 0) {
            tempStr += "("
        } else if (count == 3) {
            tempStr += ")"
        } else if (count == 6) {
            tempStr += "-"
        }
        count++
        tempStr.append(character)
    }

    textfield.text = tempStr
    return false
}
```

Comment: You have a recursion. But you are not showing the code that causes the recursion. You need to use the debugger to figure out exactly where and how the recursion is caused. What line of your delegate method triggers the recursion, and what does it call in order to do so?

Comment: Can you post your `countElements()` code?

Comment: Right, so the default UIKit textfield automatically calls this method whenever you type a character in the textfield.  If you implement this delegation method, it is called implicitly be the textfield object.  The countElements is a built in swift method, I did not write that, thanks for the responses